# Using handlebars templates is there a way to render logic if looping over not the last item in an array?

Tags: mustache, handlebars.java

Using java handlebars 4.2.1 https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java
is there a way to render logic if looping over not the last item in an array?

I know that I can do this:

```
{{#myArray}}
{{#if @last}}
{{else}}
  my rendered logic here
{{/if}}
{{/myArray}}
```

But I am looking for something with only one block, similar to
`{{^-last}}` from mustache templates

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one can do this with the unless helper:

```
{{#myArray}}
{{#unless @last}}
  my rendered logic here
{{/unless}}
{{/myArray}}
```

Per [their docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#unless) `You can use the unless helper as the inverse of the if helper. Its block will be rendered if the expression returns a falsy value.`